# What are the security implications of using boost/format?

Tags: c++, security, boost, format

I am starting to use boost/format.

When coding with boost/format, what should I pay attention to with regard to security?

Can I do the following without being concerned about security?

```
std::cout << boost::format("Hello %2%! Do you want to %1%?") 
    % user_supplied_str1 % user_supplied_str2 << std::endl;
```

What are situations where security would be an issue while using boost/format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is safe. In fact, it was safe with `printf`. Like `printf`, Boost.Format only parses its format string once, so there's no chance to insert extra format specifiers. Passing an incomplete `format` object to `boost::format` throws an exception.

I guess what you're afraid of are [format string exploits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_string_attack). Those are, I think, impossible using Boost.Format. The reasons why `printf` is vulnerable are summarized by [Cowan *et al.*](http://www.usenix.com/events/sec01/full_papers/cowanbarringer/cowanbarringer.pdf):

1. `%n` allows writing to arbitrary memory locations.
2. `varargs` doesn't allow argument counting, so a string can print out the entire heap.
3. `varargs` isn't type-safe.

Ad (1), `%n` has been [omitted](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/format/doc/format.html#printf_directives) from Boost.Format "because it does not fit in this context." Ad (2), Boost.Format doesn't use `varargs` and throws an exception when the number of arguments doesn't fit the format string. Ad (3), this is solved because the arguments to `operator%` are checked at compile time.

(I just tried to get Boost.Format to print the address of a C string in memory using a custom format string, and it won't let me.)

Further, the buffer overflow in `sprintf` is avoided because strings are allocated dynamically.

If you want to be on the safe side, don't use format strings from untrusted sources.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean security in terms of printf equivalents with incorrect type specifiers or possible buffer overflows then boost/format is perfectly fine -- even with a user supplied format string, I think. But you do have to keep in mind that it might throw an exception. Check the documentation about when and what exceptions are thrown.